# Need digital stylus for HP Elitebook Revolve 810 G1

Tags: hp-elitebook, digitization, digital-pen

I recently got a HP Elitepad Revolve 810 G1 (work PC - windows 8) that HP says on it's site has capacitive screen with digitizer. I'm looking for a stylus like the one I have with my Surface Pro (home PC - btw both the pc and stylus are awesome!) but I am having trouble.  I purchased a PL800A (HP prod) as I had read in another blog that HP said this would work with all of their tablet PC's.  It does not work.  Anyone know of a similar stylus that *would* work that has palm rejection? Do not want the regular capacitive kind - it's like a kindergarten pencil. any help would be appreciated - want to take handwritten notes in one note during meetings.

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry you bought that computer.  The stylus writing for G1 was embarrassing.  I don't have it anymore.  I saw one video of the stylus for the G2 elitepad and was marginally better which will be comparable to the G2 revolve.

Here are some forums about the stylus that works for the G1 and G2.
I need to clarify that there are 2 pens (Atmel).  The HP executive Pen (G1 and G2).  G2 pen will no work on G1 machine (the MARGINALLY BETTER ONE) but G1 pen will work on G2 machine.

Look for HP Executive Pen.  My opinion and the opinion of others, it is a waste of money.

http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-HP-ProBook-EliteBook/Stylus-Support-on-Revolve-810/m-p/6420542#M178483

http://forum.tabletpcreview.com/hewlett-packard/57307-hp-executive-pen.html